# Windows 2012 RDS RemoteApp, Access to local Drives

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, remoteapp, rds

We have an App that uses MDBs for storing Data. For performance reasons (transferring MDB-Data between Client via Network Drive to Server), I plan to deliver this App via RemoteApp. After the App is started, she does two things:

1. Reading a Configfile from c:\APPNAME\sys.mdb
2. Reading the Real data from the path specified in the sys.mdb (Network Drive, UNC-Path, Local Drive).

I setup the App under Windows 2008 R2 as RemoteApp and it worked great. The App starts and i can Specify the Path to the Real Data as D:\APPNAME\data.mdb

Now i need to setup the App under an 2012 Server. But i think, there are many changes on how RemoteApps are working. My App says, that she can not find the Configfile in c:\APPNAME\sys.mdb - either on the server nor the client. So the app has no Access to any "c:"?

I confirmed that by creating a RemoteApp for explorer.exe on both systems: 2008 shows me an explorer.exe like i would find it on my server, 2012 shows the explorer like it runs on the client (with C: of the Client).

Any Hints for me? :-)

Comment: Just to rule out the possibility that local drive redirection is masking the server's `C` drive I suggest disabling some of the redirection features from the `client settings` tab of the properties window of the collection you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. After many sleepless nights, I think this was the problem/solution:

You need to give your users permissions on c:\APPNAME with the **the same group** as the RemoteApp Collection is secured. Another group in which the user is also in does not help.

Example:

- User1
- GlobalGroupA
- GlobalGroupB

Our User1 is in both GlobalGroupA+B. You grant permission to the folder by Group-B, but the RemoteApp Collection uses GroupA - this will not work. Folder permissions need to be granted by GroupA too.

I'm not sure if this is correct, but it works now for me.

Comment: I very much doubt this explanation.